Why command `cat test.log |while read line; do echo $line ; done` would compress whitespace?
I have a file named "test.log" with contents：
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 [kthreadd]

Then I use while-read command to process it:
cat test.log |while read line; do echo $line ; done

and It returns
2 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.01 a

Wired,something was truncated.What happend?

Possible duplicate of Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?

See also When is double-quoting necessary? / Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells, Understanding "IFS= read -r line", Why is printf better than echo?, and that UUOC. You're cumulating most common shell bad practices in one line.

Specifically, since you forgot to quote $line, [kthreadd] is taken as a glob pattern that will expand to all files that match it and you likely have a file called a in the current working directory.
